# windows nodes and rundeck

Tags: windows, winrm, rundeck

Did anyone of you managed to integrate windows nodes into Rundeck? I tried everything but I'm not able to run ad-hoc commands or run a script from rundeck to windows server.
Followed steps:

- install rundeck onto Ubuntu machine
- enable winrm for windows target (tested with ansible playbooks and it
  works)
- basic connection (local admin and password)

added the nodes into resources.xml as follows:

```
<node name="winHost" connectionType="WINRM_NATIVE" node-executor="overthere-winrm" winrm-password-option="winrmPassword" winrm-protocol="http" winrm-auth-type="basic"  username="<mylocaluser>" winrmPassword="<mypassword>" description="Rundeck server node Windows" tags="" hostname="10.23.10.107" osArch="x64" osFamily="windows" osName="Microsoft Windows" osVersion="Microsoft Windows 10" />
```

- added the winrm plugin: rundeck-winrm-plugin-1.3.1.jar

My guess is that Rundeck run the commands or the scripts with "rundeck" user

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have just made today with a Windows domain server.

I setup a project with "WinRM" for "Default Node Executor" and with the following options:

- Authentication: kerberos
- WinRM Protocol: https
- HTTPS Certificate Trust: all
- HTTPS Hostname Verification: all

You need to create a file with your Kerberos config (in Ubuntu in /etc/krb5.conf, in <> your preferences, BE CAREFUL WITH UPPERCASE):

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = <TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL>
        ticket_lifetime = 24h
        renew_lifetime = 7d

[realms]
        <TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL> = {
                kdc = <dc>.<testdomain.local>
                default_domain = <testdomain.local>
                kpasswd_server = <dc>.<testdomain.local>
        }

[domain_realm]
        .<testdomain.local> = <TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL>
        <testdomain.local> = <TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL>
```

testdomain.local is the fqdn of the Windows domain
dc is the server with the kdc rol inside your domain

And finally you must configure your resources.xml inside your project ({} your preferences):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
<node name="{server}" description="Windows server node" tags="windows" osArch="x86_64" osFamily="windows" osName="Windows Server 2008" osVersion="2008"
  node-executor="overthere-winrm"
  connectionType="WINRM_INTERNAL"
  hostname="<ip or fqdn>"
  winrmEnableHttps="true"
  winrmHttpsCertificateTrustStrategy="ALLOW_ALL"
  winrmHttpsHostnameVerificationStrategy="ALLOW_ALL"
  username="{domain user}@{TESTDOMAIN.LOCAL}"
  password="secret"
  winrm-protocol="https"
  winrm-auth-type="kerberos"
  winrmPassword="secretr"
  winrm-password-option="winrmPassword"
  winrm-password-storage-path="{file with the password}"
  winrm-connection-timeout="3600000"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check below link. I am using windows servers using the over-there plugin with WinRM and OpenSSH with Cygwin to run the shell scripts. At present Overthere plugin does not support scripts execution so I am using OpenSSH. You can find the article below for step by step configs.

[Rundeck Windows nodes](http://www.techpaste.com/2015/08/rundeck-windows-nodes-configuration/)